# How can a ranger have the Snare Crafting feat at level 1?

Tags: feats, character-creation, ranger, pathfinder-2e

The [Snare Crafting](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=843) skill feat is required to create snares. The only requirement is that the character be trained in Crafting.

How can I build a level 1 ranger with Snare Crafting? Typically initial skill feats come from a character's background, but I'm not aware of a background that provides it. Are there any other options?

Comment: Are you looking for any method that a level 1 Ranger can have that Skill Feat? ie every other portion of character creation is available to change?

Comment: @Ifusaso Yes. I haven't built the character yet, so everything else is flexible at this point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Snare Crafting](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=843) is a General feat, which means a [Versatile Heritage Human](http://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=29) can take it at level 1, as can any human (or half-elf or half-orc) who takes the [General Training](http://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=68) ancestry feat.

Answer (score 10):

### Ask your GM for a custom background

P. 60 defines a background as consisting of

> Each background listed here grants two ability boosts, a skill feat, and the trained proficiency rank in two skills, one of which is a Lore skill. If you gain the trained proficiency rank in a skill from your background and would then gain the trained proficiency rank in the same skill from your class at 1st level, you instead become trained in another skill of your choice.

The backgrounds listed in the book should not be viewed as a narrow set of options, but rather a list of examples to help give you an idea of how to establish your character in the world.

Comment: I agree with you, but until the Gamemastery Guide is released with rules for customising stuff, I would err on the side of caution and stick to what’s printed where possible.

Comment: It's still a valid answer (although Snoof's is "more" accurate for staying exactly by the book without cooking something up). The fact that *all* current backgrounds are locked in at that amount of rewards makes it fairly easy to allow something like this.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to being Human/Half-Elf/Half-Orc, you could be a Kobold!  The level 1 Kobold feat Snare Setter gives you Snare Crafting for free... and if you like snare crafting, then there are some excellent reasons to be a Kobold.

Answer (score 3):

## Deep Backgrounds

If you are using the variant [Deep Backgrounds](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1318), then you can get it via having the Robbed [Major Childhood Event](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1324). It's number 16 on the table.